# edit static files (index.html) from yarn build

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used `yarn build` to create static files for my react app. Now, I want to edit the index.html file in ./build but whenever I add something it gives me an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`. Is there a correct way to edit that file?

Comment: Have you tried doing your changes in the un-built react app and running yarn build again ?

Comment: Yes, that works but I want to edit the index.html file after running yarn build

Comment: Is there any reason as to why you would want to do that ? There is an `index.html` file in the public folder in-case you want to add some external resources.

Comment: I want to pass a file to the static files. I'm trying to add a `<script src="./hello.js">` which reads hello.js in the './build directory

Comment: Try out if the answer i posted works.

Answer (score 0):

In your react project you will see a folder called public. Include your `hello.js` file in that folder. You will also find an `index.html` file. Include your script tag as follows.

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/hello.js" />
```